# Can't find submodule in package

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda3 version 4.2.0 on ubuntu (in docker).
Anaconda is installed in `/root/anaconda3` folder.
I installed [theano_bpr](https://github.com/bbc/theano-bpr) package using `pip install theano_bpr`.
Now when i open python and try `import theano_bpr`, i get the following message:
`>>> import theano_bpr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano_bpr/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from bpr import BPR
ImportError: No module named 'bpr'`
However, when i navigate to /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano_bpr/ and run python there, i'm able to import theano_bpr.
In /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano_bpr/ there are following files:
`__init__.py, bpr.py (this one is causing problems), t.py, and utils.py`.

Comment: Installed in that location, your Anaconda will only be accessible by user root. Is that what you want? I would recommend doing your development as an ordinary user, not root and using virtualenv or something similar to isolate your environment.

Comment: well, i'm the only user, so that's ok for me. Note that i'm noob Linux user so i don't know if that is the good solution.

Comment: As an experienced Linux user, I can tell you it's not. As root, it's easy to destroy your system by accidentally typing the wrong thing. Or create security holes without realizing it. The very first best practice to learn in Linux is to reserve the root user only for tasks that require root access and stay in an ordinary user for ordinary work.